# Como faço para redirencionar e enviar valor url get para outra página usando Javascript?

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web, url, get

Estou pegando um item da url com esse código :

```
function GetQueryString(a)
{
    a = a || window.location.search.substr(1).split('&').concat(window.location.hash.substr(1).split("&"));

    if (typeof a === "string")
        a = a.split("#").join("&").split("&");


    if (!a) return {};

    var b = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
    {

        var p = a[i].split('=');

        if (p.length != 2) continue;

        b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }

    return b;
}


var qs = GetQueryString();

  qs["item"]; // Item que eu estou pegando da url ex: 
     https://meusite.com/pagina.php?item=(valor que eu quero pegar)
```

E depois que efetuar esse processo, eu gostaria que com o valor obtido da

variável "qs" concatenasse com o link da nova página que seria redirecionado após 3 segundos, eu estou usando esse código:

```
setTimeout("document.location = 'https://www.meusite.com/pagina.php?item='" + `qs['item']`,3000);
```

Como posso arrumar este código ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função não retorna um array. Alias, você está referenciando uma chave, como se fosse um array associativo. Isso não existe no JavaScript.

O retorno é um objeto `JSON` e deve ser acessado dessa forma: `qs.item`. O código correto(coloquei um alert para mostrar a URL) para redirecionar é o seguinte:

```
function GetQueryString(a)
{
    a = a || window.location.search.substr(1).split('&').concat(window.location.hash.substr(1).split("&"));

    if (typeof a === "string")
        a = a.split("#").join("&").split("&");


    if (!a) return {};

    var b = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
    {

        var p = a[i].split('=');

        if (p.length != 2) continue;

        b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }

    return b;
}


var qs = GetQueryString();

URL = "https://meusite.com/pagina.php?item=" + qs.item;

alert(URL);

window.location = URL;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @mauhumor, mais uma dúvida se você pudesse me ajudar, como eu poderia por aquele  `qs.item` dentro de um atributo html como por exemplo o atributo que eu estou usando é `data-channel-external-id="(valor da url aqui dentro)"`

Comment: Pode utilizar o método "setAttribute" documentado aqui: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

Comment: Pois é eu estava tentando esse antes mas não estava dando certo aqui, eu estava fazendo o seguinte, fiz essa função `function urlid() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("BUTTON")[0].setAttribute("data-channel-external-id", "qs.item"); } ` e no atributo dentro do HTML botei `data-channel-external-id="urlid()"` porém não consegui, o que acha que posso estar fazendo de errado?